# GO / Golang run project on Docker issues - Cannot find packages (internal folders)

Tags: docker, go, containers, google-app-engine-golang

I'm trying to run my first Golang project on Docker.
While I succeeded with a simple "hello world" application, I'm facing some difficulties with a slightly more structured project.

The project has some folders inside which I imported in the main.go file.
When I try to run my solution on Docker, it gets stuck while loading those "packages".

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY *.go ./

RUN go env GOROOT
RUN go build -o /my-api

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/my-api" ]
```

This is the error I get

```
Step 8/10 : RUN go build -o /my-api
 ---> Running in c1c9d1058caa
main.go:10:2: package my-api/Repositories is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/my-api/Repositories)
main.go:11:2: package my-api/Settings is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/my-api/Settings)
```

One thing I noticed is that this path

```
/usr/local/go/src/my-api/Settings
```

should be

```
/usr/local/gocode/src/my-api/Settings
```

on my local machine

Here is a glimpse into how my project is structured

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: `RUN go env GOROOT` what is the purpose of this?

Comment: Can you add GOROOT and GOPATH environment variables values?

Comment: `COPY *.go ./` does not copy the Repositories and Settings folders.

Comment: @dwij sorry, it is nothing really. It is a leftover of something I was trying to do

Comment: @Gari Singh thanks for your answer. How can I make it copy also the folders?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine
RUN apk add build-base

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app
RUN go build -o /my-api

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "/my-api" ]
```

This will copy the contents of the local directory on your local machine to `/app` in the image.

Note: To build a "production grade" image, I'd use a multistage build:

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine as builder
RUN apk add build-base

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN go build -o /my-api

FROM alpine:3.14
COPY --from=builder /my-api /
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "/my-api" ]
```

Comment: Modified the above to include gcc in the image as it's not included in the golang base image

Comment: If you are looking to build a production container, then I'd use a multistage build as well so that you don't ship Go and the build tools in your image.  I'll modify my answer above this option as well.